# lualatex fontspec replaces some available glyphs in math font with ones from body text font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, luatex, fontspec, unicode-math

I am using lualatex with fontspec to typeset math equations in one font, and text in another font. During my tests I found that math in my typeset document doesn't really look as good as some specimens I had seen online. Upon further investigation I found that even if the font chosen for math (using `\setmathfont`) has the required glyphs (like lowercase 'd'), lualatex composes math by replacing some of those glyphs with roman font face loaded at the time of `\setmathfont`!

Look at the lowercase 'd' in the following two images. The first one was compiled with font "TeX Gyre Pagella Math" for math, and default font (Latin Modern) for main text. Second one was compiled with "TeX Gyre Pagella Math" for math, with "TeX Gyre Pagella" for main text. *As a side note, I had started my testing with Cambria Math, and that too has the same problem. So it is definitely not a font related issue.*

First (without TeX Gyre Pagella for main text, lowercase 'd' is from Latin Modern, rest of the glyphs are not)
[image: Without TeX Gyre Pagella for main text]

Second (with TeX Gyre Pagella for main text, lowercase 'd' is probably from TeX Gyre Pagella and not from TeX Gyre Pagella Math; since they are same equation looks fine)

[image: With TeX Gyre Pagella for main text]

Complete code (please read NOTE before `\setmathfont` on how to regenerate both cases):

```
% >> lualatex testmathfont.tex
\documentclass[notitlepage,letterpaper]{article}

%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=2in,right=2in,top=1in,bottom=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[expansion=alltext,shrink=20,stretch=20]{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% NOTE:: Compile 1: keep following line commented, Compile 2: uncomment following line
%\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]\vspace*{\baselineskip}

$\displaystyle\int_a^b x^2\;\mathrm{d}x= \tfrac{1}{3} x^3 \Big|_a^b$\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\blindtext[1]\vspace*{\baselineskip}

$a_0+\cfrac{1}{a_1+\cfrac{1}{a_2+\cfrac{1}{a_3+\cdots}}}$\vspace*{\baselineskip}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes mathrm switch to the text font. Use \symrm instead

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks!! I wonder why that's so, and where would I find documentation for such corners? It is hard one to miss unless someone really zooms into an equation. Is there any other math command that also picks up glyphs from surrounding text (roman) face? Also it would be cleaner interface if one could specify something like `\setmathfont[romanfamily=Tex Gyre Pagella]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}`, otherwise in a document that uses multiple fonts, one would have to always remember to change roman face to one that matches math equations (something that's easier to forget) for every equation

Comment: Well did you check the unicode-math documentation?